# Rotate function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

I want to write a function in Haskell that rotates the list given as the second argument by the number of positions indicated by the first argument. Using pattern matching, implement a recursive function

I have written the following function:

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate 0 [y]= [y]
rotate x [y]= rotate((x-1) [tail [y] ++ head [y]])
```

but this function always produces a error. Is there any way to solve it?
The function should do the following when it runs:

```
rotate 1 "abcdef"
"bcdefa"
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: You can't easily delete a question which has upvoted answers, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[y]` does not mean "let `y` be a list". It means "this argument is a list containing one element called `y`". You have the right structure, but you don't need the brackets around the `y`.

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate 0 y = y
rotate x y = rotate (x-1) (tail y ++ [head y])
```

Comment: Good answer, however, I think that mentioning pattern matching vs partial functions (`head`, `tail`) might be a good addition.

Comment: obligatory dv for the top voted answer with needlessly partial solution. sry.

Answer (score 2):

**TL&DR**

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate = drop <> take
```

In Haskell the most concise but also a curious way to rotate a list could be using the `Semigroup` type class instance of the function type `(a -> b)`. Lets check the relevant part of the instance.

```
instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) where
        f <> g = \x -> f x <> g x
```

First things first, `<>` is in fact the inline version of the `mappend` function from the `Monoid` type class.

Then we see, the `Semigroup b =>` constraint in the type signature states that the return type `b` should also be a member of `Semigroup` type class. Since we use `drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` and `take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` we can quickly notice that `b` is in fact another function with type signature `[a] -> [a]` so it is a member of `Semigroup` type class if and only if it's `b`, which happens to be `[a]` is also a member of the `Semigroup` type class and it is.

```
instance Semigroup [a] where
        (<>) = (++)
```

So everything holds so far but how does it work?

We can deduce from the type signatures as follows;

- `(drop :: Int -> ([a] -> [a])) <> (take :: Int -> ([a] -> [a]))` is
- `\n -> (drop n :: [a] -> [a]) <> (take n :: [a] -> [a])` which is
- `\n -> \xs -> (drop n xs :: [a]) <> (take n xs :: [a])` which is
- `\n -> \xs -> (drop n xs) ++ (take n xs)`

This is basically better than the answers using recursive `++` operator to add the head as a singleton list to the end of the tail since it yields an O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: not to mention it being non-partial, unlike those other solutions. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate 0 x = x
rotate times (x:xs) = rotate (times - 1) (xs ++ [x])
```