# Haskell: how can I take each number from a list separately?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to duplicate a "-" character for 0 to n number of times, add a '*' and add a duplicate of "-" character again for n to 0 times recursively, e.g.:
If n = 5, I'd like the answer to be:

```
*-----

-*----

--*---

---*--

----*-

-----*




duplicate :: String -> Int -> String -- will be used to duplicate spaces
duplicate string n = 
    concat $ replicate n string

block :: Int -> String
block n =
    duplicate ***from 0 to n*** "-" ++ '*' ++ duplicate ***from n to 0*** "-"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Try writing a function that takes the index at which to insert the * as an argument, then calling that function with all the desired indices.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to create a function that prints one line:

```
line width idx = duplicate "-" idx ++ "*" ++ duplicate "-" (width - idx - 1) ++ "\n"
```

And then map it over a list `[0..(n-1)]`, then concatenate results:

```
block n = concat $ map (line n) [0..(n-1)]
```

Or, for a more intuitively looking solution, you can do the same thing as a list comprehension:

```
block n = concat
    [ duplicate "-" i ++ "*" ++ duplicate "-" (n - i - 1) ++ "\n"
    | i <- [0..(n-1)]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple code to handle this job could be;

```
\n -> (drop <> take) <$> [n+1,n..1] <*> ['*':replicate n '-']
```

I had explained about `drop <> take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` [in a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58328879/4543207). fmap (`<$>`) and applicative op (`<*>`) should be clear.